# How to connect shaft to gearbox?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, gears

I downloaded a 3D  model of a planetary gearbox from **Rossi** website, so the 3D model is reliable. As you can see, there is no keyway on the opening of the gearbox, thus i can't connect my shaft with traditional key designs. [image]

And here is axial section view of the gearbox, the shaft sits inside the left side. 
[image]

What woud be the best way to connect the shaft with gearbox ? should the shaft has exactly the form of inside gearbox i mean can the shaft come directly into the gearbox? or i should have consider a soort of coupling ? 
Here is the suggested output side details:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you considered apart from keys? What is suggested on the Website? What amount of power are you putting through the device?

Comment: @SolarMike I've not considered anything, that's what i'm asking help for. The power of synchronous motor is about 11kW. I update my question by putting more detail on the output side.

Comment: Most gearbox mfgs offer a range of options as standard issue. The Part Number includes a section identifying the shaft treatments. I'm not familiar with Rossi, but contact them for details. Such options often don't show up on drawings because they may affect the published dimensions.